# Popup not working following feature query using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.

I'm creating a web map based on this example:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=tasks-query

Except I've modified it so that the drop-down list is dynamically populated based on the values available in an attribute column (MajBas in this instance). Everything works well EXCEPT that the pop-up content does not display properly after querying a feature. Specifically, only the pop-up title shows but not any of the content.

Why might this be happening?

The complete code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>

    <title>Project viewer</title>

    <style>
      
      html,
      body,
      #mainViewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      h2 {
        color: black;
        font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
        line-height: 1;
      } 
      
      p {
        color: black;
        font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
      } 
      
      div {
      line-height: 0;
      }
      
      #optionsDiv {
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 15px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
        -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 15px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
        box-shadow: 3px 2px 15px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
        opacity: 0.90;
      }
      
      #drop-downs {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }
      
      widget {
        /* Fill in later to style drop down widget */
      }
      
      #printResults {
        line-height: 1;
        font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
      }
      
      #doBtn {
        box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #9fb4f2;
        background-color:#1a1b1f;
        border: 0px solid #4e6096;
        display:inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#ffffff;
        padding:6px 12px;
        text-decoration:none;
        border: 0px;
        outline:none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      }
      #doBtn:hover {
        background-color:#494b51;
        outline:none;
      }
      #doBtn:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
        border: 0px;
        outline:none;
      }
      
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

    <script>
       require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Basemap",
        "esri/widgets/LayerList",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/PopupTemplate",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
        "esri/tasks/support/Query",
        "esri/widgets/Home"
        ], function(
          Map,
          MapView,
          Basemap,
          LayerList,
          FeatureLayer,
          PopupTemplate,
          GraphicsLayer,
          QueryTask,
          Query,
          Home
        ){
         
        var basinUrl =   "https://services.arcgis.com/v01gqwM5QqNysAAi/arcgis/rest/services/Chesapeake_Bay_major_watersheds_feature/FeatureServer/0";  
         
        //* Define the popup content for each result
        var popupTemplate = {
          title: "{MajBas}",
          fieldInfos: [
            {
              fieldName: "MajBas",
              label: "Major basin"
            }
          ],
          content:
            "{MajBas} test"
        };
         
        // Layer - project footprints
       const basinLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: basinUrl,
        outFields: ["*"],
        visible: false
        });
         
        // Layer - dark nav basemap 
       const basemap = Basemap.fromId("streets-night-vector");
         
       //** Point querytask to project boundary URL
        var qTask = new QueryTask({
          url: basinUrl
        });
         
       //** Set the query parameters to always return geometry and all fields.
       //** Returning geometry allows us to display results on the map/view
        var params = new Query({
          returnGeometry: true,
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
         
       //* GraphicsLayer for displaying results
       var resultsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
       
       var map = new Map({
           basemap : basemap,
          layers: [basinLayer, resultsLayer]
       });

        var mainView = new MapView({
          container: "mainViewDiv",
          map: map,
          popup: {
            highlightEnabled: false,
            dockEnabled: true,
            dockOptions: {
              breakpoint: false,
              position: "top-right"
            }
          },
          center: [-75.325395, 40.306275],
          zoom: 5
        });
         
        // create home widget 
        var homeWidget = new Home({
          view: mainView
        });
        
         // add widget with drop-down options
        mainView.ui.add("optionsDiv", {
          position: "bottom-left",
          index: 0
        });
        
        // add home widget
        mainView.ui.add(homeWidget, {
          position: "top-left",
          index: 0
        });
         
        //* for drop down
        var basinTypeSelect = document.getElementById("valSelect");
         
         //* query all features from the basin layer
        mainView
          .when(function () {
            return basinLayer.when(function () {
              var query = basinLayer.createQuery();
              return basinLayer.queryFeatures(query);
              document.getElementById("doBtn").addEventListener("click", doQuery); 
            });
          })
          .then(getValues)
          .then(getUniqueValues)
          .then(addToSelect)
         
         //* return an array of all the values in the
        //* basin name field
        function getValues(response) {
          var features = response.features;
          var values = features.map(function (feature) {
            return feature.attributes.MajBas;
          });
          return values;
        }
         
        //* return an array of unique values in
        //* the MajBas field of the basin layer
        function getUniqueValues(values) {
          var uniqueValues = [];

          values.forEach(function (item, i) {
            if (
              (uniqueValues.length < 1 || uniqueValues.indexOf(item) === -1) &&
              item !== ""
            ) {
              uniqueValues.push(item);
            }
          });
          return uniqueValues;
        }
       
         //* Add the unique values to the basin type
        //* select element. This will allow the user
        //* to filter basin by name.
        function addToSelect(values) {
          values.sort();
          values.forEach(function (value) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = value;
            basinTypeSelect.add(option);
          });
    
        }
         
        //** Call doQuery() each time the button is clicked
        mainView.when(function () {
          mainView.ui.add("optionsDiv", "bottom-left");
          document.getElementById("doBtn").addEventListener("click", doQuery);
        });

        //**
        var attributeName = document.getElementById("MajBas");

        // Executes each time the button is clicked
        function doQuery() {
          // Clear the results from a previous query
          resultsLayer.removeAll();
          // Build new query
          params.where =
            "MajBas =" + "'" + basinTypeSelect.value + "'";

          // executes query and calls getResults() once promise is resolved
          // promiseRejected() is called if the promise is rejected
          qTask.execute(params).then(getResults).catch(promiseRejected);
        }

        // Called each time the promise is resolved
        function getResults(response) {
          // Loop through each results and assign a symbol and PopupTemplate
          var basinResults = response.features.map(function (feature) {
            // Sets the symbol of each resulting feature
            feature.symbol = {
              type: "simple-fill", 
              color: [212, 161, 87, 0.25],
              outline: {  // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                color: [128, 128, 128, 0.5],
                width: "0.5px"
               }
            };
            
            feature.popupTemplate = popupTemplate;
            return feature;
          });

          resultsLayer.addMany(basinResults);
          
          // animate to the results after they are added to the map
          mainView
            .goTo(basinResults)
            .then(function () {
              mainView.popup.open({
                features: basinResults,
                featureMenuOpen: true,
                updateLocationEnabled: true
              });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              if (error.name != "AbortError") {
                console.error(error);
              }
            });

          // print the number of results returned to the user
          document.getElementById("printResults").innerHTML =
            basinResults.length + " result(s) found";
        }

        // Called each time the promise is rejected
        function promiseRejected(error) {
          console.error("Promise rejected: ", error.message);
          }         
         
      
        
       });
       
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mainViewDiv"></div>
    <div id="optionsDiv">
      <h2>Example</h2><br>
        <div id="drop-downs">
          <p><b>Basin</b></p>
        <select id="valSelect" class="widget"></select>
      </div>
      <div align="center"><button id="doBtn">Search</button></div>
      <p><div align="center"><span id="printResults"></span></div></p>
    </div>
 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@happymappy, this is happening because of your CSS:

```
  div {
      line-height: 0;
  }
```

Which is making the content of your popup not display. Change it to something more specific, for example:

```
div#drop-downs {
   line-height: 0;
}
```